# PHP's fopen slow for large files; is there a better alternative?

Tags: php

PHP's `fopen` is really slow when the file is really big. When I read the file using Python (single thread), the operation is x100 faster.

My project requires us to use PHP for reading file data. Are there any other methods to handle file reads with PHP that would offer better performance?

BTW - memory is not an issue I'm cleaning in runtime.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: the file is local .................

Answer (score 2):

PHP cURL is the fastest according to [this website](http://rickydoesit.com/php/php-file_get_contents-v-s-php-fopen-v-s-php-curl-speed-and-performance/) that did benchmark tests on fopen, file_get_contents, and curl.

Comment: Dead link. That's why one shouldn't post links on answers

Comment: @LucasBustamante not good to copy the contents of a lengthy benchmark test onto StackOverflow. Not only for obvious reasons, but also because it's copyright infringement.  The answer states that a website did benchmark tests, and specifies that cURL is the fastest.  And reason NOT to link it, even if it eventually becomes broken.  Instead of a comment, just suggest an edit to remove the broken link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misleading at some point, as you're comparing python "read" fact with fopen, which doesn't read anything, fopen just open a pointer(stream) to a file.

Maybe, it's the way you're reading which is very slow, it can be the buffer size you could be using as I see a lot of ready-for-use implementations, as it reads small pieces, it's of course slow for large files, just see, if you read 4k by time and you have a 4G file size to be read, it'll loop 1.000.000 times, of course it'll be slow.
e.g:

```
while (!feof($handle))
{
 $file .= fread($handle, 4096); //4k read by once
}
```

// whole data will be read at once system can fit it into memory, for both scenarios.
A faster way would be:

```
$file = fread ($handle, filesize ($filename));
```

Or even, which is almost the same as above, but php c core is doing it:

```
$file = file_get_contents($filename));
```

So try to use a bigger buffer in case of fread, or use the full size of file in it if your system can handle this in memory and your php ini option supports the amount of allocation as well as you can use **stream_get_contents** to get it in an "optimized" way.

Also, CURL is for remote files which can be accessed through something like an web browser.
Because of it, it'll probably be very better and faster using **file_get_contents or fopen for local files** as you won't need to spend new connections and resources from webserver to get your own local file.